# How to remove a container disk and reclaim space with main partition? (Similar to another question)

Tags: macos, disk-utility, catalina, apfs

[image: diskutil list]

So basically im an idiot and dug myself a hole. Im nearly out of this mess but I still have one thing to do. Just need to get the data back that is in these containers. Help is much appreciated. I can send you some cookies

Answer (score 1):

To convert a container to free space requires two commands. For example, `disk1s5` is a APFS container. To convert to free space, you would need to enter the following commands.

```
sudo diskutil apfs deleteContainer disk1s5
sudo diskutil eraseVolume free none disk1s5
```

Free space can be added to a container, if the free space reside immediately after the container. In your case, if you converted `disk1s5`, `disk1s4` and `disk1s3` to free space, then you probably would be able add this free space to `disk1s2`, by entering the command given below.

```
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk1s2 0
```

Comment: haven't done this yet cuz my computer is like 3 or 4 feet away. too far. But when I get to I know this will work cuz u r THE BEST MAN. Thank you friend